# Can't use inherited protocol in class as variable in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols, type-alias, associated-types

Why can't I achieve the following:

Protocols:

```
public protocol IDataManager {
    associatedtype T : NSManagedObject

    var delegate: IDataManagerDelegate? {get set}
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<T>! { get set }
    func numberOfSections() -> Int
}

public protocol IStudentDataManager: IDataManager {
    typealias T = Student
    func findExmatriculatedStudents() -> Students?
}
```

Implementation:

```
class StudentDataManager: NSObject, IStudentDataManager {
    var delegate: IDataManagerDelegate?
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Student>
    func numberOfSections() -> Int { return 0 }
}
```

Using the protocol:

```
class StudentVM: NSObject {
    public var dataManager: IStudentDataManager!
}

let object = StudentVM()
object.dataManager = StudentDataManager()
```

> Protocol 'IStudentDataManager' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Comment: You cannot use protocol as type during instantiation/property type. 'public var dataManager' must be some type that conforms to your IStudentDataManager protocol

Comment: Thanks, that works. Is there another way I can achieve the interchangeability of dataManager? I don't want to set the implementation in class.

Comment: subclassing. You can subclass the class you created as type for dataManager, and set dataManager property to subclass of your type

Comment: Agreed with subclassing. Protocols with associated types are a very complicated tool and there are many, many corner cases that will bite you. If you already have subclasses, there is almost never a reason to involve protocols as well. You've already used class inheritance; don't mix it with a completely different kind of inheritance (protocols)